# move comma separated items from multiline textbox to listbox

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

i have a multiline textbox which has comma separated value e.g: java,sql,php i want all text items to be moved to listbox on click of a add button mu desired output :
java
sql
php

```
 StringBuilder bulder = new StringBuilder();
        string[] oldstring = { TextBox1.Text};
        foreach (string str in oldstring)
        {
            bulder.Append(str);
            bulder.Append(",");
        }
        string[] newstring = bulder.ToString().Split(',');
        TextBox1.Text = bulder.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
```

by using this code am getting values as java,sql,php only what am doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you creating an array `oldstring` with a single item in it, and then looping through that single item? Isn't that the same as `bulder.Append(TextBox1.Text + ",");`?

Comment: You never used a `listbox`

Comment: yes. as i am doing lots of trial and error to achieve that

Answer (score 1):

You are not splitting the `TextBox1.Text` correctly: you're not reading each line as a separate `string`. You are reading the entire string and then splitting it.

You can accomplish what you are asking much more simply. This is a simple version of what I believe you're trying to do, and it could even be simplified further if desired.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] oldString = TextBox1.Text.Split(
        new string[]{","},
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(oldString);
}
```

This is a button click event that splits the text from `TextBox1` by `,` characters, then adds each item to `ListBox1` using the `Items.AddRange(string[] items)` method.

If we wanted to manually update the listbox one item at a time instead, we can use a `foreach` loop instead.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] oldString = TextBox1.Text.Split(
        new string[]{","},
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (string item in oldString)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: if i use above code its giving me error "Error: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection.AddRange(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem[])' has some invalid arguments"

Comment: I didn't know that this was a web control. We can loop through the items to accomplish the same effect. Please check my edit.